# Sequential updating breaks ergodicity of Metropolis–Hastings algorithm of the Ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, ergodicity

I believe I have this question under control but I am puzzled at why I have not found people pointing this out.

For simplicity consider a 1D ferromagnetic Ising model with periodic boundary conditions: $H=-J\sum_{i=1}^Ns_is_{i+1}$. The simplest algorithm to simulate this would likely be a Metropolis that would go like

- choose a random site $i\in\{1,\dots,N\}$;
- propose a flip $s_i\rightarrow-s_i$;
- accept the flip with probability $p=\min\{1,e^{-\beta\left(E'-E\right)}\}$ where $E$ ($E^\prime$) is the energy of the system before (after) the flip.

This algorithm is such that we always flip the spin if at least one of its neighbors is in a different state.

A common improvement of this algorithm is to eliminate the randomness of choosing the site $i$ at random but rather use a deterministic choice. For example, go sequentially through spins $1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow \dots\rightarrow N \rightarrow 1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow\dots$
It is simple to see that this will break detailed balance but still satisfies "global balance":

\begin{equation}
P\left(A\right)=\sum_B P\left(B\right)T\left(B\rightarrow A\right)
\end{equation}
where the sum is over configurations, $P\left(A\right)$ is the probability of finding the system in the configuration $A$ and $T\left(B\rightarrow A\right)$ is the probability to go from configuration $A$ to configuration $B$. This I can prove and I have no issue here.

What seems that people do not point out is that this algorithm is not ergodic, which is not guaranteed by the above equation. This is easily seen in any 1D system with an odd number of spins. For example, if we have 3 spins, the configuration $\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow$ will always be mapped $\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow$ and vice versa.

It is not hard to fix this problem. For example instead of "propose a flip $s_i\rightarrow-s_i$" we can change to propose a flip with a certain probability $0<p_\mathrm{proposing}<1$. Then it is easy to see that ergodicity is restored in the sequential update case.

Even though this is simple enough, I find it strange that I have never seen this pointed out before. Am I missing something? Is there any good reason why this is usually omitted or perhaps is there other reason I have not seen this before?

Comment: See other network questions on the matter: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2405961, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299780 (identical questions by same user, but one got an "answer" via comments that seems useful).

Comment: Maybe [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378437113008091?via%3Dihub) addresses some of your questions.

Comment: Thank you for the link to other posts and the paper! I will dive a bit deeper into the paper to see if it clarifies this situation for me.